# Is std::equal_to reliable for float types?

Tags: c++, std, equality, floating-accuracy

To be more exact, does `std::equal_to<float>()(float a,float b)` or `std::equal_to<double>()(double a,double b)` does the somewhat better float equality like `abs(diff) < EPSILON` or just `a==b`?

Comment: I'd never trust one arbitrary float to exactly equal another. The best plan is that they're within some acceptable mathematical distance, as you note there.

Comment: Note that using [a good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to) would answer this question for you. *"Function object for performing comparisons. Unless specialised, invokes `operator==` on type T."*

Comment: The problem is that your statement of the 'right' way to compare floating point values paints with too broad a brush. Sometimes that's the right way, sometimes 'epsilon' has to be chosen based on careful numerical analysis of the exact code producing the floating point values, somtimes exact == equality is correct. It depends on what exactly you're doing.

Comment: Note that your definition of "correct float equality" is actually incorrect in nearly all cases! This comparision would be only meaningful for floating point values close to 1.0 and even then it is most likely incorrect: when you need to extend the range of values to be considered equal you'll need a proper error analysis. The resulting term _may_ involve `EPSILON` but just `EPSILON` is rather unlikely to be correct.

Comment: @DietmarKühl @bames53 I understand that. I just thought that it would have a more accurate equality check than just `==`

Comment: Why would an equality operator consider values which are not equal (clearly `x != x + epsilon` for `epsilon != 0`)? The one thing which would neat to get fixed in an equality function is that `x == x` may yield `false` for objects with a floating point type but `std::equal_to<F>` doesn't do that either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::equal_to` uses `==` to perform the comparison. If you want to compare with a tolerance, you'll have to write that yourself. (Or use a library.)

Comment: @Nawaz I don't think you're allowed to specialize standard library templates on built-in types.

Comment: @Nawaz *results in undefined behavior unless the declaration depends on a user-defined name of external linkage*

Comment: The relevant quote for C++11 is *"A program may add a template specialization
for any standard library template to namespace `std` only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type
and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly
prohibited."* (17.6.4.2.1 [namespace.std])

Comment: After some quick testing, I found this to be true.